# Bulkifying code

Tags: apex, bulkification

The following is my piece of code, I am trying to bulkify it. Should I define map first and then use the values in insert operation. Please help me.

```
set<Id> DocIDList = new set<Id>();
for(ContentDocumentLink Link : [SELECT ContentDocumentId,Id,IsDeleted,LinkedEntityId,Visibility FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =:sObject.Id]){
    DocIDList.add(Link.ContentDocumentId);
}
contverList = new List<ContentVersion>();
contverList = [select Title, Description, FileType,Owner.Name, VersionNumber,CreatedDate from ContentVersion 
                where ContentDocumentId in :DocIDList AND IsLatest = true
                AND FileType != 'SNOTE'];   
for(ContentVersion objacc : contverList){                  

    for(ContentVersion con1 : [select Id, Checksum, ContentDocumentId,  FileExtension, FileType, FirstPublishLocationId, OwnerId, PathOnClient, Title, VersionData, VersionNumber 
                       FROM ContentVersion where Id = :objacc.Id]){
        insert new ContentVersion(
            Title = con1.Title, 
            PathOnClient = con1.PathOnClient, 
            VersionData = con1.VersionData, 
            FirstPublishLocationId = Sobject.Id
        );
    }                                                     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: I didn't notice that you also had a query being performed in inner loop, so that should be fixed as well.

You can do this as below. Declare a list of `ContentVersion` object. In your inner for loop, where you are making the `insert` call, instead of making the dml call, just add those objects to the list instead. And then once you are out of the loop, you just call insert there.

A good place to start on this topic is this [**blog post**](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices).

```
List<ContentVersion> myContentList = new List<ContentVersion>();

for(ContentVersion objacc : contverList){                  

    for(ContentVersion con1 : <fix this to iterate over a list instead of making a DML within a loop) {

        // instead of inserting here, 
        // just keep on adding to the list and insert later -- bulkify!
        myContentList.add(new ContentVersion(
            Title = con1.Title, 
            PathOnClient = con1.PathOnClient, 
            VersionData = con1.VersionData, 
            FirstPublishLocationId = Sobject.Id
        ));
    }                                                     
} // close outer loop

if(myContenList.size() > 0) {
    insert myContentList;
}
```

Comment: @ Jayant Das : Thank you very much, that solved my problem and also got clear idea on bulkifying. Cheers !!

Comment: Glad that it helpd. I will additionally recommend to go through some documentation and trailhead to learn for more on this topic so that you can get more information around it and that you can always consider this in future while writing such code. All the best!

Comment: There are other enhancements you can do, this was just a direct answer to help you with how to remove your dml out of the loop. But you should revisit your inner loop here as well.